# Не запускается эмулятор в Android Studio

Tags: android-sdk, android-studio, android, sdk

Установил новый Android Studio 1.0. Закачал все СДК. Всё есть. Запускаю проект - что-то грузит, грузит и ничего не происходит. Вообще. Помогите кто чем может.

Answer (score 2):

Приветствую!!
Советую использовать эмулятор Genymotion, продукт бесплатный!
Регистрируешься у них на сайте, скачиваешь, пользуешься, работа эмулятора впечатляет!
Довольно шустрый.

```
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/pricing
```

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь зависит все от Вашего оборудования на компьютере, а именно от процессора в большей части.
В зависимости от того, какой у Вас процессор, можно поступить по-разному. 
Если Intel какой-нибудь CoreIX, то просто отлично [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) Вам поможет. Или же использовать [KVM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213273)(Kernel Based Virtual Machine) (также поддерживается AMD).

Ну или самый простой способ установить Genymotion, ну и, естественно, VirtualBox. 
Обычно если не стартует эмулятор, то просто обарудование не тянет.

Comment: Не запускается на ноуте и компе. На ноуте проц i3 и 4 гига оперативы. Всегда работал андроид студио. Тут и  HAXM установил, и всё равно не запускается. Просто ничего не происходит. На компе - АМД, 3 гига оперативы. Тоже всегда всё работало норм до новой версии. И опять же не открывается эмулятор

Comment: Вообще не открывается ? Или на черном экране висит ? Посмотрите логи вроде в EventViewer или как-то так.